# PHP: $_GET image location for Facebook Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook, image

Is it possible to get the location of an image that is on a webpage?
I want to use it for `og:image`.

example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php 'get the image location' ?>" />
```

It is for a Open Graph Facebook share.

Comment: It will be very hard to answer without more code. Why don't you set a variable with the path to this image when you generate your html code ?

Comment: I would like to have a php code that get a image location from the webpage. What you @j0k suggest is good but when there are more images i want to share them.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't have multiple image into the meta tag og:image. You should only put the more revelant one from all images of the page.

Comment: What does that mean, "get image location"? Where is the image whose location you want to get? Why don't you know the image's location?

Comment: Are you trying to get the image source, given a website URL? Something like http://example.com and get the source of the first image on the page?

Comment: @Claudiu Yes something like that! Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long answer and since you haven't provide code for what you tried doing, here's a high level description of what you should do:

(Note: OP is trying to get an image source from an HTML document, if any)

You need to download the page with PHP, find an `<img>` tag, grab the source for it and return that as a result. Depending on where you're getting your images from, you might want to get a only images from a certain location (not just the first image which could be a logo or even a meaningless 1sq px image).

For example, if you want to get the first user shared image on 9gag, you would look for the `<img>` tag in the ".img-wrap" div. An easy way to parse the HTML document is using: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ - the page is pretty self explanatory.

You'll want to wrap all that in a function such as `getImageFromWebsite(URL)` and have that function return the `src` attribute of the `<img>`

Downsides to doing this:

- The website you're pointing this to will be responsible for your content. Even if you 'know' what images you're including, these can and will probably change with time.
- The structure of the website you're pointing to might change. Your function will have to change too.
- The website might decide to block your server if the decide you consume too much bandwidth.
- You're not in control of the content

I can add more to the list. It's fun to practice doing it, but not very practical.

Comment: Make sure you mark this is correct if it works for you :)